# Get Textarea value from posted form in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, post

This is my form

```c#
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPayments", "BookingPathLabelsCms"))
        {
            if (@Model.DisplayName == "Payment Labels")
            { 
            <textarea id="seeit" name="seeit" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>

            <textarea id="seeitNoSelect" name="seeitNoSelect" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>

            <div class="cmsButtonContainer">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "BookingPathLabelsCms")">Cancel it</a>
                <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save it"@* onmouseover="copyto();"*@ />
            </div>
            }
        }
```

And this is my controller action

```c#
public ActionResult EditPayments(BookingPathLabelsCmsViewModel model)
{
     string txtarea = Request.Form["seeit"];
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Am not getting the values of textareas here,but values in the breakpoint ,see image.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is a value there? If nothing was entered in the textarea, `Request.Form["seeit"]` will be null as well, thought the key will exist.

Comment: yeah am entering values in there,but is there any chance the values will get lost ?

Comment: You should go back to your MVC tutorials. I'm sorry, but manually pulling out fields from the `Request.Form` is completely against the strongly typed models present in the MVC framework.

Comment: use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` it will populate in model.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead and Satpal : Thanks fro your suggestions,i recently switched to MVC platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPayments", "BookingPathLabelsCms"))
{
    if (@Model.DisplayName == "Payment Labels")
    { 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SeeIt)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SeeItNoSelect)

        <div class="cmsButtonContainer">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "BookingPathLabelsCms")">Cancel it</a>
            <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save it"@* onmouseover="copyto();"*@ />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Of course, your ViewModel BookingPathLabelsCmsViewModel should have SeeIt and SeeItNoSelect properties. After that, MVC will bind correctly entered data.

Answer (score 0):

> First create a class with property.

```
public class TextAreaProperty
{
    public string MyTextAreaValue { get; set; }
}
```

> Use on the view declare like:

```
@model <project_name>.Models.<Class_name>
```

> In this case:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TextAreaProperty
```

> Use this textArea Razor

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x=> x.MyTextAreaValue)
```

> On method post receiving parameter type TextAreaProperty

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TextAreaProperty textAreaProperty)
{
    return View();
}
```

> You will get the value from textAreProperty.